# Upgrade Python - Why is there no official guide for this?

Tags: macos, upgrade, python

I currently have Python 3.9 installed on my Mac. However, I wanted to upgrade to version 3.11. Especially since the old versions will eventually no longer be supported with updates for security.

Now I was looking how best to do the upgrade. I don't use homebrew and I don't really plan to (unless there are good arguments for it).

On the official Python site I couldn't find any documentation on how to cleanly uninstall Python on macOS. And an upgrade, as far as I found out, only works if there is a version jump from e.g. 3.10.1 to 3.10.2. Then you can simply install it "over". But otherwise you have several versions, which I do not want and do not need. Also in books for beginners it is nowhere how to delete or update all the things. This also surprises me a lot, since experts always advise you to keep the software up to date.
Anyway, I also want to avoid that the versions somehow "overlap" or interfere. Because that can happen if you just put the Python folder in the trash. Anyway, I read about such problems here.

Could you guys help me with this please? I don't know much about programming either and just want to learn it or use it for university. But also keep my Mac clean and know what is installed.

Thx!

Comment: There’s the Python that comes with macOS which cannot be uninstalled.  You have to install and maintain the version you want to use separately

Comment: It is not a version that comes from macOS itself. I installed 3.9 myself at the time because I needed it for a course. And as far as I know, Apple doesn't ship Python in MacOS anymore since a few versions or am I wrong?

Comment: If you installed it, you maintain it by upgrading it as you normally would.  You installing it (and presumably using it) would make whether it was included macOS  moot. Just upgrade it per your preferred method.

Comment: But that doesn't work just like that with Python. During an upgrade, several versions are installed in parallel and any dependencies remain. And I'm looking for a best practice here. I have described the problems above. Or do I have a mistake somewhere?
Because on the official site of Python there is no info about upgrading or uninstalling on macOS.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.9 and plan to install 3.11? How did you conclude that you would have multiple versions installed in your particular case?

Comment: I installed Python 3.9 from the official site using the installer. That I have several versions of it on the Mac, I have read in old posts here and Stack Overflow respectively. Is this no longer up to date?

Comment: The problem with the question right now that it a bit hypothetical and based on hearsay/undisclosed sources. There *are* guides on how to upgrade python on macOS out there, why not follow one of them?

Comment: @nohillside Can you kindly link me this tutorial please? Because I have not found any that was also easy to implement. And got along without homebrew.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=upgrade+python+macos&t=iphone&ia=qa  has a lot of ressources on the topic.

Comment: Thank your, but I have seen it all before. But either homebrew is used, something with a virtual environment (which I'm not familiar with and it's too complicated for me) or simply installed "over it". However, the problem is not addressed if you want to upgrade from version 3.X to 3.Y and both are then installed. Also no reference to an official source.

Comment: If you install a new version from python.org it just overwrites the python executable. If you are doing anything serious with python you need to learn about virtual environments - either the venv module python (and then pyenv to manage and allow multiple versions of python) or I would use conda which does both

Comment: @mmmmmm Thank you very much! Then I had probably old or wrong (?) Information about it?
I read it among other things here, but also elsewhere in Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013809/how-to-update-python-3-6-to-3-7-using-mac-terminal

But I will inform myself about virtual environments! Thanks for the tip. But as far as I read so far, a virtual environment does not affect the main Python installation, which should be kept up to date anyway, right? Because without a "normal" Python installation there are no virtual environments.

Comment: The default python venv does not change python version - but conda and I think pyenv do allow different versions of python in parallel (as does macports and homebrew)

Comment: It's the multiple versions which is most confusing. I have 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 installed via homebrew. It is not clear (to me) which is needed.